# Why do these two array formulas produce different results?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Cell A1 is empty, Cell A2 contains "test".

When creating an array formula in cell B1 like this:

```
{=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("a1:a2")),0)}
```

it produces the correct result "2" since cell A2 contains a non-blank value.

However when creating an array formula in cell C1 which gets row number using the row(a2) function, it results in "1".

```
={MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("a1:a"&row(a2))),0)}
```

How can the second formula be modified to use the row(a2) function and get the same results as the first formula, "2" instead of "1"?

Seems like it should work since row(a2) returns 2 so the address string ends up being "a1:a2", same as in the first formula.  The point of this is to make the range it searches be dynamic based on the starting row 1 and ending at row(a2) so that if, for example, five rows are inserted between rows 1 and 2, then the a1:a2 range will automatically adjust to a1:a7.

Comment: Are the two formulas both looking at cells `A1:A2` within the same sheet, or in different sheets?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but try using $A$1:$A2 instead of INDIRECT("A1:A" & row(a2))

Comment: They two formulas are on the same sheet.  One is in column b, the other in column C.  Adding $ to the formula doesn't make a difference.